# How to layout a UITableViewCell may or may not have images using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

As shown in the image, the cell may or may not have images and the number of image is various. It also has text content with variant height. (The cells are all in the same tableview.)

**The text height(number of lines) is variant no matter there is image or not.**

How to layout this kind of cell using AutoLayout? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So when there are no images, show a second line of text?

Comment: @KelvinLau Nope, the text height is variant as well. Thanks for being interested in the question.

Comment: You can set constraints with (top space, bottom space, center X, leading space, trailing space)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of vertical/horizontal spacing constraints will achieve your desired effect. To get a varying text height, you can set the `lines` property in the attributes inspector to `0`. The text will make a second line automatically, while your vertical layout constraints will push anything bound to the `UILabel`.

You will however need to accommodate for the cell height for some situations however... but that's for another story.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UILabel (myLabel) with numberOfLines = 0 and a container UIView (myImageContainerView) to hold the Images. Both myLabel and myImageContainerView would define their own height based on their content. If there are no images the containerImageView would be height zero. Then you just set up the constraints between these Views.

Here is an attempt to represent this an ASCII diagram:
The | (pipe symbol represents a vertical Spacing constraint)
The <-> represents a horizontal spacing constraint

```
----------------------------
         |
<->   myLabel                 <->
         |
<->    myImageContainerView   <->
         |
-----------------------------
```

Lastly you will need a dynamic height UITableViewCell which you can achieve by setting this on your tableView:

`myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

Comment: Thank you very much. But it seems I have to layout the cell in code?

Comment: @Evan You can achieve this in IB too. Set a UIImage inside the myImageContainerView to have a top, leading, trailing and bottom constraint to make myImageContainerView's height dependant on the image. If you set the image to nil,  myImageContainerView will have zero height. UILabel with numberOfLines=0 has dynamic height automatically

Comment: So I have just try it out, but after I set the imageview to nil, myImageContainerView still has has a non-zero height. Another problem is that after I set the imageView to nil, the cell after that( with images) can not show the images, because it no longer has an imageView.

Comment: @Evan Thats probably because `UITableViewCell` got reused. Instead you could use `prepareForReuse` method in custom table cell class to reset the properties to its default state so that when the cell gets re used, it gets a brand new layout as intended.